# Insert text after the 3rd semicolon

Tags: vb.net

I have a string separated with semicolons. I want to insert a text after the 3rd semicolon.

String example: `PRT;03;BOM0012002;001;Plate;STEEL;9340.876279;`

Comment: Congratulations. Put some thought into the problem, make an attempt to implement some code and, if you encounter an actual problem, post a question that includes all the relevant information. *"I want to do X, tell me how"* is not a "question" for SO.

Comment: Hey Stefan! Welcome to StackOverflow. What's your question here? Are you not sure how to go about doing what you'd like to do? If so, write that in the question (e.g. "I want to insert text after the 3rd semicolon, but I'm not sure how to do that. I think I have to find the semicolon first"). If you've already tried but it doesn't work, show us what is happening or what error you're seeing. If you have any code at all, add that to the question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using regular expressions here:

```
Dim input As String
Dim output As String
input = "PRT;03;BOM0012002;001;Plate;STEEL;9340.876279;"
output = Regex.Replace(input, "^((?:[^;]+;){3})(.*)", "$1NEW TEXT;$2")
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

This prints:

```
PRT;03;BOM0012002;NEW TEXT;001;Plate;STEEL;9340.876279;
                  ^^^^ new text added in correct position
```

The regex pattern `^((?:[^;]+;){3})(.*)` matches and captures the first three terms, as well whatever follows, in separate capture groups.  It then concatentates together the replacement, adding the `NEW TEXT;` content after the third semicolon.